# Can't define width for a DIV

Tags: html

I'm making a game website, and I'm using the DIV tag for the genre menu.  While making the menu, I found that I am not able to set the size of the DIV elements for the menu.  I'm using  if that matters.
HTML:

```
    <div class="center">
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='all.html';">All</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='action.html';">Action</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='arcade.html';">Arcade</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='racing.html';">Racing</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='rpg.html';">PRG</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='skill.html';">Skill</div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='strategy.html';">Strategy/Puzzle</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='shooting.html';">Shooting</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='sports.html';">Sports</div>
     <div class="menu" onclick="location.href='gamegarage.html';">GameGarage</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body
    {
    background-color:black;
    color:rgb(0,255,0);
    font-family:"Comic Sans MS";
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    .center
    {
    text-align:center;
    }
    .menu
    {
    font-size:1.35em;
    display:inline;
    width:250px;
    cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;
    border:5px solid #00FF00;
    }
    div
    {
    margin-bottom:15px;
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your CSS for your menu tag to this:

```
.center .menu
{
font-size:1.35em;
display:inline-block;
width:250px;
cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;
border:5px solid #00FF00;
}
```

also you should change your onclick events to `window.location.href = "link"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
display:block
```

or

```
display:inline-block
```

instead of inline in your menu class.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the width of a div, you need to set

```
.menu {
    display: inline-block;
```

Now you can define div's width, height and vertical-align.

```
    width: 250px; height: 1.4em; /* height: auto inherit 130px */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you have a outer box '.center', that's boxed or inline-boxed, but will be much higher as a .menu is, it will be aligned in middle of the outer '.center' box.